# When I try to build app by Android studio , I get the following error that the Gradle tasks connects timeout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Information:Gradle tasks [assemble]
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a network issue. Try to run this on Gradle CLI:

```
./gradlew tasks --offline
```

See the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).

or

Goto **Settings** >> **Build, Execution, Deployment** >> **Build tools** >> **Gradle**
and tick on "**Offline Work**".

Comment: You're welcome. If that's the right answer, why don't you accept the answer so that it helps others?